# Detecting specific reactions to a message without on_reaction_add

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

**Constraints of the problem:**

1. My python bot needs to iterate through a list of messages to find reactions (I have that implemented and working), so I cannot use "on_reaction" or async's related to reactions on the final implementation
2. I don't want to use custom classes (I don't know how to convert my current code to be compatible and don't want to bother). I believe that means payload is out of the question?

**What I have done:**
I began with this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iRHBGZWOwVo&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGAHdJdtEl0-XiRfPRAvpbSz&index=6
I will summarize the relevant parts of the video, so you don't have to watch. I wrote code that uses aynscs to print the reaction emojis to the shell. I then copied and pasted the images into a comment in my code, and from there into the code where relevant. This worked great for 6 of the 8 emojis I am interested in detecting.

Detecting looks like such (for the working 6 of 8)
`if str(reaction.emoji) == '':`

**The problem:**
I used the same technique for all 8 emojis, but my bot isn't detecting two different ones, despite them being present in the search messages. These two emojis are `:heart:` and `:hearts:` by Discord's syntax. How can I get these emojis to be detected? I've tried every combination of `reaction.emojis.name` and `str(reaction.emojis.name)` imaginable.

Answer (score 1):

I found this - and used the "copy" function and pasted it into the code. Worked like a charm. The discord `:hearts:` is just the Heart Suit emoji.
https://emojipedia.org/red-heart/